# In Final Fantasy VII, what were the 1/35 Soldier items for?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

In Final Fantasy VII, you could collect items called 1/35 Soldier, but they never seemed to have any use.

This has bugged me for years. Are these items used for anything at all in the game?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no use for the 1/35 Soldiers in Final Fantasy 7.
But if you purchase the vacation home in Costa Del Sol, the soldiers will be up on display there.

Oh and if anyone cares, there are 12 in the set.

And for more info on items in FF7: 
http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_VII_items
is a great reference.

Comment: That's a great use!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get more than 12 x 1/35 Soldiers, up to the item limit of 99, as you can receive them as a prize in the Speed Square in the Golden Saucer. The same goes for the Masamune Blade and Super Sweeper items, neither of which have a purpose in the game.

Comment: I think that "there are 12 in the set" means "there are 12 different", not that its quantity is caped to 12.

Answer (score -1):

i do not know the validity of this, but i read on a forum back in like '05, that once you got the set you could take it to the guy in the cave, and he would give you something for the set. there was also a rumor that they were a part of a way to get a sephiroth clone, or an aeris clone in your party. I kind of doubt it though, personally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Guys i have an update on this.

I have the psx platinum version of the game and i found a use for these items in all my play throughouts of the game.

the 1/35 Soldiers and super sweeper are part of a set o items to protect fort condor. 
If you have a set number of cash and soldiers / super sweeper they appear and protect the reactor. The specifics i don't have but are related with the mini quest of each major development in the story will activate a new battle in fort condor. (ex: before getting the buggy/ after getting the buggy).

I know this isn't much but i saw the super sweeper protecting the reactor when in mini battle mode in fort condor. (i don't have a picture,sorry )
I did not use cheats and i couldn't find the trigger for this either then taking the car to do ALL battles in fort condor until i reached nibelheim.